# Remover /ufeff de resultado do json_encode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Ao fazer um cadastro utilizando ajax, o success não executa os comandos de dentro do mesmo, ao analisar o codigo reparei que existe um /ufeff no valor retornado pelo php e acho que isso que esta causando o erro.

Codigo php:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",true);
require "Conexao.php";

if (verificacaocCliente() == true) {
    $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST["nome"]);
    $cpf = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST["cpf"]);
    $rg = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST["rg"]);
    $telefone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST["telefone"]);
    $celular = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST["celular"]);
    $endereco = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST["endereco"]);
    $bairro = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST["bairro"]);
    $uf = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST["uf"]);
    $cidade = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST["cidade"]);
    $date_nasc = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST["date_nasc"]);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST["email"]);
    $data = date("Y/m/d");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO cliente (Nome, CPF, RG, Telefone, Celular, Endereco, Bairro, UF, Cidade, Data_Nascimento, Email, Destaque, Negativo, Data_Insercao) VALUES ('$nome', '$cpf', '$rg', '$telefone', '$celular', '$endereco', '$bairro', '$uf', '$cidade', '$date_nasc', '$email', 0, 0, '$data')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));

    if ($result) {
        $response = array("success" => true);
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "Scriptsphp/novoCliente.php",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { nome: nome, cpf: cpf, rg: rg, telefone: telefone, celular: celular, endereco: endereco, bairro: bairro, uf: uf, cidade: cidade, date_nasc: date_nasc, email: email },
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#sbmt_cCliente").val("Cadastrando...");
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response) {
                        $("#erro_cCliente").slideDown("fast").html("Cliente cadastrado !");
                        $("#nome, #cpf, #rg, #telefone, #celular, #endereco, #bairro, #email").val("").css({ "border": "1px solid #7D96BF" });
                        $("#uf, #cidade").val("Selecione...").css({ "border": "1px solid #7D96BF" });
                        $("#date_nasc").val("dd/mm/aaaa").css({ "border": "1px solid #7D96BF" });
                    } else {
                        $("#erro_cCliente").slideDown("fast").html("Erro no cadastro !");
                        $("#sbmt_cCliente").val("Cadastrar");
                    }
                }
```

como posso remover o /ufeff ?

Comment: Você já tentou trocar o `if(response)` por `if(response.success)`?

Comment: Antes do `json_encode` no PHP, coloque `http_response_code(200)`.

Comment: Ainda não, testei as duas dicas mas continua igual, os dados são inseridos no banco mas não e executado o que tem dentro do success

Comment: Qual versão do JQuery você está usando?

Comment: estou usando o jquery 3.2.0

Comment: Tente trocar `success: function(response)` por `done: function(response)` então.

Comment: Ainda não, o estanho é que estava funcionando desse jeito a pouco tempo atras, e eu fiz pequenas mudanças no php como o $data = date("Y/m/d"), e depois dessas modificações ele parou de funcionar o success mas continua funcionando a inserção no banco @KillerJack

Comment: Estranho mesmo. Adicione após o `beforeSend`: `always: function(obj, msg) { console.log(msg); },` e veja no devtools ou equivalente o que aparece.

Comment: Desculpe pelo equivoco, mas nunca usei o aways antes, e ao usar agora percebo que nada aparece no console, provavelmente por que fiz algo errado, porem, eu repare algo que pode ser o problema disso tudo, quando dou o `echo json_encode($response);` existe um `\ufeff` antes do `{"success":true}` (coisa que não acontece em nenhum outro echo), poderia ser isso ?

Comment: Atualize sua pergunta com o código atual. Qual editor você está usando? Tente trocar o encode do arquivo para algo sem BOM.

Comment: Estou utilizando o vscode, e fiz um padrao de encode em todo o site, reformulei a pergunta com os codigos

Comment: Mude seu `Content-Type` para `application/json`.

Comment: continua com o  /ufeff

Comment: Você trocou o encoding do arquivo no seu editor? VSCode tem a opção de escolher encoding em algum canto, faz tempo que não o uso então não sei te falar exatamente onde. Se ele tiver com BOM lá, ele sempre vai colocar ao salvar o arquivo.

Comment: O problema era realmente o BOM, porem estava procurando no lugar errado, o problema não estava nesse arquivo, e sim no `conexao.php`, obrigado pela paciência e ajuda @KillerJack e @Anderson Carlos Woss